# In BBC's Dracula series, how did Dracula and Van Helsing end up having sex at the center of the Sun?

Tags: dracula, dracula-2020

At the very last (and rather [controversial](https://io9.gizmodo.com/steven-moffats-dracula-was-like-good-sex-that-got-bad-r-1840836510)) scene of BBC's 2020 *Dracula* series, the Count and Van Helsing are seen having sex at the center of the Sun:

[image]

However, it was left unclear if this really happened, was a dream or even a metaphor of some sort.

Arguments for having really happened:

> The Count has demonstrated several impressive supernatural powers, e.g. is immortal, can turn into bats, can create mist, can hypnotize  his victims, can control animals etc etc.

Also, the Count

> is not damaged by the sunlight! Albeit, he realizes this only at the end.

Finally, it is shown that vampires in general are not destroyed by fire, hence the Count may have really survived at the core of the Sun.

Arguments for being a dream:

> While feeding on his victims he can cause them to dream, presumably to pacify them.

This is relevant as

> just moments before, the Count was seen committing suicide by feeding on a dying (from cancer) Van Helsing since a dying person's blood is venom for a vampire.

**So, did this scene really happen or was it a dream?**

Comment: Not seen the show, but aren't vampires usually quite averse to sunlight?

Comment: This is also true in this show, sort of....

Comment: So it must have not really happened then? It'll be a dream as you say, or a metaphor.

Comment: Not necessarily, as there's a loophole in the whole sunlight thing, but I can't say more without giving away some major spoilers. Hence my question! I added a comment in a spoiler section.

Comment: Is it definitely meant to be the sun?

Comment: Yes, the scene zooms out and it's definitely the sun. I'll see if I can find a video from YouTube.

Comment: Forget about Dracula, how can Van Helsing survive being in the center of the sun?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist See this: https://youtu.be/MqMxISTHf-I?t=684

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It’s a dream

In the final scene she says:

> This isn’t real. This is a dream.

Dracula responds:

> Of course it is.

We saw in the previous episode that while drinking blood, Dracula is able to implant a vision in his victim (such as the chess game between him and Agatha).

In the final scene, his is draining her blood and giving them both a dream while he does so.

Presumably the dream is intended to make both their deaths more bearable as he tells her:

> Did you think I’d let [dying] hurt?